# Collect HostCPU utilisation and disk I/O speed using XenServer Java API

Tags: java, xen

I would like to use XenServer Java API to collect some performance information from a pool of hosts, but I am having some trouble getting the HostCPU utilisation. For all CPUs the utilisation comes with 0.0 value, and I don't know why. I have not found a way to get the disk I/O speed (read and write in b/s). Has anyone had succeeded in getting this data?

Answer (score 1):

In XenServer version 5.5, the way these metrics are stored has changed, and it is now recommended to use the XML over HTTP API instead.

The `getVCPUsUtilisation` method will always return 0.0 by default, but you can make it work as it did in earlier versions with the workaround documented [here](http://www.jansipke.nl/getting-xenserver-vm-metrics-in-java/).

Comment: I changed my implementation to use the HTTP API, but seems it do not return some static informations (like CPU power, model, etc). So, I am using both APIs. HTTP to retrieve dynamic information and Java API to retrieve static data! But I still wondering to know how XenCenter works. Because it shows the resources utilization in real time. The unique way I can imagine doing this is by making these HTTP calls all the time, but it sounds not a good option to me. Do you, or someone else, know a better way to do that? Thanks, Irussell!

Comment: @viniciusbraga do you know how we can get disk io information for domain using libvirt java api ?